# Spring data and hibernate - model validations - exception translation

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, spring-data, hibernate-validator

I use spring-data and hibernate. Now I would like to apply some validation to my model. In most cases I would like to apply simple validation like null-checking etc. But in some cases I would like to apply more strict validation, such as email-validation. I found very useful feature in Hibernate validator - the @Email annotation. It works very well but here is the problem:

If i try to save a model with null value, then the following exception is thrown:

*org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException*

But if I try to save a model with non-null but non-email value (let's say *asdfgh*), then the following exception is thrown:

*javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException*

***I would love to see only one type of exception in both cases***, because in both cases the model didn't pass the validation and I would like just to worry about only one exception type in my exception-handling code.

I tried to add *PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor* to my bean configuration, but it looks like it does not change anything.

Do you have an idea how to "unify" this exceptions?

Model:

```
@Entity
public class ValidationModel {
    ...

    @Email
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ValidationModelRepository extends JpaRepository<ValidationModel, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Column(nullable = false)` is not a validation check. It's a JPA constraint.

To validate that a value is not null, use `@NotNull`.

Comment: ahh you're right! how could I forgot about that? :) thanks!